# configure: error: curl required for remote access. Install curl or build with --disable-dap

Tags: ubuntu, curl, netcdf

When I run the `CPPFLAGS='-I${H5DIR}/include -I${ZDIR}/include' LDFLAGS='-L${H5DIR}/lib -L${ZDIR}/lib' ./configure --prefix=${NCDIR}`  command to install the netcdf-c I got the following error.

```
checking for curl_easy_setopt in -lcurl... no  checking for library containing curl_easy_setopt... no configure: error: curl required for remote access. Install curl build with disable-dap.
```

the error is related to installing curl. but I have installed it and its installation folder can be generated as follow:

```
which curl
/home/habtamu/anaconda3/bin/curl
```

why is curl not accessible to the netcdf- installation procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `libcurl`: `sudo yum install libcurl-devel` or `sudo apt install libcurl-dev`